# Is my query lasting for long time or it's database connection

Tags: python, django, postgresql, cpu-usage

I'm coding in `Django` and I have a management command in one of my apps. This commands code is as follows :

```
while True:
    # Run a query on database
    # Do some processing on it
    time.sleep(6 * 3600) # six hours sleep
```

As you can see, in an infinite loop, every six hours, I fetch some objects from database, do some processing on them and repeat again after six hours.

My database is `postgresql`, I'm using `python3` with `Django`.

The problem is that when I use `htop` on my system to monitor server status, I see that `CPU time` of this commands database connection is so large, as you see in picture below :
[image]

and the related query in database is :
[image]

My question is that, is django holding the connection to database for my command and `CPU time` shown is for the whole life of infinite loop, or it's the `CPU usage` of one of my queries in just one loop?

In another words, should I care about the very low speed of my query or it's OK and time shown is for the whole time?

Comment: to avoid burden on connections and processing please use background Tasks or Queues for simple intigration use https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ or write script in some py file and use crons

Comment: The problem is Django use atomic blocks to perform operations in loops so it wont commit the data unless loop is completed which makes connection open until loop ends https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/transactions/

Comment: Maybe you could run a test using [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html).